# On the polar representation of an inner product.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-learning

Take $H$ an inner product space. $x,y \in H$.

Take $b = |<x,y>|$ . Then the polar representation of $<x,y>$ is:

$$<x,y> = be^{i\theta}$$ for some $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$.

Why is this? If the answer is too long a reference will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Any complex number can be written in the form $re^{i\theta}$ right?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Then that's your answer- $<x,y>$ is a complex number..

Answer (score 2):

For any complex number $z$ we have

$$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$$
where $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ is the principal argument of $z$.

Comment: I recall now, thanks :) .

Comment: You're welcome.